# XML Writer - Unable to override UTF16 to UTF8

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build the XML using XMLWriter but it contains encoding UTF-16. I tried so solution to modify that to UTF-8. But nothing is working

```
      var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true),
                Indent = false,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the UTF8String Writer

```
   private class UTF8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use XDEclaration.

```
  var doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
        new XElement("root", new XAttribute("note", "boogers"))
    );
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(".\\test.xml", new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
```